# neo4j -- Find all shortest paths between more than 2 nodes

Tags: neo4j

For example,I want to query allShortestPaths between 3 nodes(A,B,C),it means i want to query:
1. the allShortestPaths between A and B
2. the allShortestPaths between C and B
3. the allShortestPaths between A and C

but I only find the allShortestPaths query to get allShortestPaths between two nodes.

As follow:

```
MATCH (node1:E { eid:"a9c2f114-796f-4934-a2d0-04bb3345e1d2" }),
(node2:E { eid:"01968dd2-1ed6-472d-82e9-be7701036b3b" }), 
p = allShortestPaths((node1)-[*]-(node2))
RETURN p LIMIT 25
```

***I am wondering if there exists a allShortestPaths query supporting more than 2 nodes input?***

Now,to search 3 nodes,I have to invoke the "allShortestPaths" three times,as follow:

```
MATCH (node1:E { eid:"b73ade90-dfa1-4b94-bd0f-c16fd93bd680" }),
(node2:E { eid:"ddb5c52d-7002-4ac7-87d5-0f727f2ab3e7" }),
(node3:E { eid:"0398b081-6676-4a91-856b-abbabaee5e70" }) , 
p = allShortestPaths((node1)-[*]-(node2)),
q = allShortestPaths((node3)-[*]-(node2)),
m = allShortestPaths((node3)-[*]-(node1))
RETURN p,q,m LIMIT 10
```

***What i want to do is to search allShortestPaths between arbitrary number of nodes.***

***So far,I intend to write user-defined procedures,but it will costs more time.I wondering who can provide better advice.***

i want to search search allShortestPaths between serveral nodes.
such as: `allShortestPaths((a)-[*]-(b)-[*]-(c)-[*]-(a))`
I want get the all shortest path between a and b,b and c,c and a in a query

Comment: What exactly is your use case here? If you can verbalize the problem you're trying to solve, it may help us to provide an alternate approach.

Comment: i want to search search allShortestPaths between serveral nodes.
such as: allShortestPaths((a)-[*]-(b)-[*]-(c)-[*]-(a)) .but i havenot found the appropriate query to realize.        
I want get the all shortest path between a and b,b and c,c and a in a query

Comment: This sounds like the traveling salesman problem. With 3 nodes order doesn't matter. Does the order of visitation matter to you with 4 nodes or more?

Comment: nodes order doesn't matter,also the visitaton order doesn't matter

Taking nodes A/B/C for example:

I want to get  all the shortest pathes of A--B,B--C,and A--C.

Comment: Official Neo4j Solution: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/all-shortest-paths-between-set-of-nodes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a nested loops:

```
// Array of id
WITH ["b73ade90-dfa1-4b94-bd0f-c16fd93bd680",
      "ddb5c52d-7002-4ac7-87d5-0f727f2ab3e7",
      "0398b081-6676-4a91-856b-abbabaee5e70"] as IDS

UNWIND IDS as vid
   //  Looking for the desired nodes
   MATCH (N:E {id: vid})
WITH collect(N) as NS

// Nested loops
UNWIND RANGE(0, size(NS)-2) as i1
  UNWIND RANGE(i1+1, size(NS)-1) as i2

    WITH NS[i1] as N1, 
         NS[i2] as N2
    // Get paths
    MATCH ps = allShortestPaths((N1)-[*]-(N2))

RETURN ps
```

Comment: I was actually planning to use nested loops. but when using nested loop,the cost is the sum of every allShortestPaths((N1)-[*]-(N2)). I am wondering whether has more effcient cypher query to do.What I wish is that the cost time is max of every allShortestPaths((N1)-[*]-(N2)) rather than sum of.

Comment: In the latest version of APOC Procedures (3.0.4.1 or later, to be used with the corresponding x.x.x version of Neo4j), you should be able to use pairsMin() and a single loop through each pairing to process your allShortestPaths. It won't execute in parallel, there's currently no way to do this.

Comment: I am wondering whether i can write my own parallel "allShortestPaths" algorithm by using the neo4j Java traversal API.
Has anyone realize a more efficient algorithm than the "allShortestPaths"  cypher query.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j doesn't provide a version of `allShortestPaths` taking multiple patterns, which is what you want:

```
allShortestPaths((node1)-[*]-(node2), (node1)-[*]-(node3), (node2)-[*]-(node3))
```

You wish to optimize the traversals by piggy-backing on the first one to do the second one at the same time, but there's no such thing out of the box, and it wouldn't do the third one either. It's a really specific use case.

You either have to call `allShortestPaths` *n*(n-1)* times (for *n* nodes) in Cypher, or try implementing it yourself server-side in a [procedure](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/procedures/#_user_defined_procedures) using the [Traversal framework](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorial-traversal).

Answer (score 0):

here a sample cypher

```
MATCH (n:Entity) where n.name IN {names}
WITH collect(n) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as n
UNWIND nodes as m
WITH * WHERE id(n) < id(m)
MATCH path = allShortestPaths( (n)-[*..4]-(m) )
RETURN path
```

see https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/all-shortest-paths-between-set-of-nodes/ for more